# How convert IQueryable<IQueryable<Page>> to IQueryable<Page> with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

```
var page = pagesRepository.GetPages();
var categoryPages = page.ChildCategoryPages;
var articlePages = categoryPages.Select(x => x.ChildPages);
```

`articlePages` is `IQueryable<IQueryable<Page>>`.
but I need all pages in `IQueryable<Page>`.

How to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var articlePages = categoryPages.SelectMany(x => x.ChildPages);
```